# Yahoo YQL: find city WOEID by coordinates

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

How to get city's WOEID if I know latitude and longitude of city using YQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the YQL console, you can search for the nearest place with a 'placeTypeName.code' of 7

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

```
SELECT * FROM geo.places WHERE text="{$seedLat}, {$seedLong}" AND placeTypeName.code = 7
```

The REST query for this query would look something like;

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20geo.places%20WHERE%20text%3D%22{$seedLat}%2C%20{$seedLong}%22%20AND%20placeTypeName.code%20%3D%207&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=
```

Obviously replacing `$seedLat` and `$seedLong` with your own co-ordinates :)

Comment: Would you show us with a sample of actual URL that's actually working http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20geo.places%20WHERE%20text%3D%225%2C%20106%22%20AND%20placeTypeName.code%20%3D%207 doesn't work.

Comment: Try using decimals instead of integers as parameters, YQL doesn't seem to like both being passed as ints.

Comment: nothing shows up either. Tell me what's the WOEID of SELECT * FROM geo.places WHERE text="6.0,105.0" AND placeTypeName.code = 7

Comment: First if there's nothing in their database at that lat/long there will be no result, check the result count first. Second I've run that query many thousands of times via the api, it was working fine. However I've just run the script for same for 30 mins and it's always returning 0 results, looks like Yahoo has turned it off. Lastly you should do your own homework, build a testing script yourself and try the REST query with a range of lat/long pairs.

Comment: This answer is no longer applicable as Yahoo has made changes.

The answers below by shshaw and Chuanyung Lin are now the correct answers.

Answer (score 8):

For those still trying to look up the WOEID by coordinates, the other answers are now outdated. Use the `geo.placefinder` datatable to look up the latitude and longitude, and the WOEID will be in the returned results.

Via YQL:

```
SELECT * FROM geo.placefinder WHERE text="{$seedLat}, {$seedLon}" and gflags="R"
```

*([Test it out on the YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20geo.placefinder%20WHERE%20text%3D%2246.9062324%2C-102.78000830000002%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22).)*

Via REST:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20geo.placefinder%20WHERE%20text%3D%22{$seedLat}%2C{$seedLon}%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22
```

Comment: when I use this query it is giving result as null

select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="{$17.4186947},{$78.5425238}" and gflags="R")

Comment: @Navakanth: Your query should be [`SELECT * FROM weather.forecast WHERE woeid IN (SELECT woeid FROM geo.placefinder WHERE text="17.4186947,78.5425238" AND gflags="R")`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%2217.4186947%2C78.5425238%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22))

Comment: This is no longer working. I believe YQL have shut dwon access to the placefinder table. `Tenant 'query_yahooapis_com' access to 'Resource [tenantName=query_yahooapis_com, type=TABLE, name=geo.placefinder, locatorType=FILE, url=/home/y/share/manhattan/application/tenantBundles/yql_query_yahooapis_com_manhattan_v2/YQL-INF/restdefs/geo.placefinder.xml, useUrl=false]' is denied.`

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the official web page:
http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/free_YQL.html

Here is an exmpale:
select * from geo.placefinder where text="37.416275,-122.025092" and gflags="R"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Yahoo has made the `geo.placefinder` table non-public, which means access requires a valid application ID and OAuth authentication (see [Free Non-Commercial YQL Table Usage](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/free_YQL.html)). If you just want the WOEID and you know the city and state, you can use the `geo.places` table instead:

```
select * from geo.places where text="Hanover, PA" AND placeTypeName.code = 7
```

<kbd>[YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22Hanover%2C%20PA%22%20AND%20placeTypeName.code%20%3D%207)</kbd>

If a result is found, the WOEID will be returned as `data.query.results.place.woeid`.

However, this isn't perfect. In Pennsylvania we have (at least) three places that can show up when searching for "Hanover" (Hanover in York County, Township of Hanover in Beaver County, and Hanover Township in Luzerne County). This may or may not affect your results when searching using this method. Using a postal code should increase the accuracy of the results, and it is possible to filter the results by the known latitude/longitude using the `boundingBox` property:

```
select * from geo.places where text="Eagle, Wisconsin" AND
  boundingBox.southWest.latitude <= 42.9147280 AND
  boundingBox.southWest.longitude <= -88.4426340 AND
  boundingBox.northEast.latitude >= 42.9147280 AND
  boundingBox.northEast.longitude >= -88.4426340 AND
  placeTypeName.code = 7
```

<kbd>[YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22Eagle%2C%20Wisconsin%22%20AND%20boundingBox.southWest.latitude%20%3C%3D%2042.9147280%20AND%20boundingBox.southWest.longitude%20%3C%3D%20-88.4426340%20AND%20boundingBox.northEast.latitude%20%3E%3D%2042.9147280%20AND%20boundingBox.northEast.longitude%20%3E%3D%20-88.4426340%20AND%20placeTypeName.code%20%3D%207)</kbd>

You will still need to provide one of several required keys (`text` is a valid required key), so this doesn't qualify as searching solely by geographical coordinates, but hopefully this counts as second best.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers work anymore, but this does.

You need to combined the flicker table in the query, like so:

`select place.woeid from flickr.places where lat="" and lon="" and api_key=""`

Getting a API KEY from Flickr is instant:
https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/

Comment: Yahoo YQL no more?